# Return values that are the same in two intervals - problems with SELECT ... IN ()

Tags: influxdb

I'd like my InfluxDB to return `address` values from `probes_address` that are the same in two intervals.

This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM "probes_address"
WHERE TIME >= 1509262992757ms
  AND TIME <= 1509286166260ms
  AND "address" IN
    (SELECT "address"
     FROM "probes_address"
     WHERE TIME >= 1509291526184ms
       AND TIME <= 1509308535996ms)
```

InfluxDB returns:

```
error parsing query: found IN, expected ; at line 1, char 104
```

How to make the query I want?

Answer (score 0):

InfluxDB does not support `IN`. You will have to use 2 separate queries to achieve what you want. First, run the inner query to get `address` values. After that, either dynamically generate the second query using `OR`, or just get all events from a certain time period and filter using the result of the first query.

[You'll find relevant documentation here.](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/query_language/data_exploration/)

Comment: So, I can't achieve what I want using just queries?

Comment: If by "just queries" you mean either 1 query or 2 queries that will always look the same - then no. The second query (the outer query in your example) will change depending on the result of the first (inner) one, since you can only use `OR`.

Perhaps you can figure out a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

InfluxQL is very limited and does not support the `IN` operator, nor a nested query in the `where` clause, nor many other handy SQL constructs.

You could use a subquery in the `from` clause to get matching addresses in either interval. In an outer query you could then filter those that have the minimum time in the first interval and the maximum time in the other.

I could not test it, but the idea is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (
        SELECT "address", MIN(TIME) AS "mintime", MAX(TIME) AS "maxtime"
        FROM   "probes_address"
        WHERE  (TIME >= 1509262992757ms AND TIME <= 1509286166260ms)
           OR  (TIME >= 1509291526184ms AND TIME <= 1509308535996ms)
        GROUP BY "address"
       )
WHERE  "mintime" <= 1509286166260ms AND "maxtime" >= 1509291526184ms
```

Comment: `error parsing query: mixing multiple selector functions with tags or fields is not supported`

Comment: Why InfluxQL is so limited? :(